# Custom jobs for json payloads in spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am having below payload in event hub, Able to root the same to spark using structured streaming. Now I have to write custom jobs for each sensor type. How I could check the column value of streaming DF and root it to different function? Actually each type have different set of parameters and I need to fetch the custom schema from SQL DB, I am stuck here.

```
{
"Sensor_Id": 1,
"Sensor_Type":"Type1",
"Parameter":
{
"Parameter1":12
"Parameter1":34
"Parameter1":56
}
}
```

Below the code snippet to fetch the payload. I am able to read the content apart from parameter, I am thinking to fetch the schema from SQL DB by querying using Sensor_Type and read the parameter part using from_json. And later write custom jobs. Is there any way to achieve this in Spark 2.4?

```
val eventhubs = spark.readStream
      .format("eventhubs")
      .options(eventHubsConf.toMap)
      .load()
val jsonSchema = new StructType().add("Sensor_Id", StringType)
      .add("Sensor_Type", StringType)
      .add("Parameter", StringType)
val events = eventhubs.select(from_json($"body".cast("String"),jsonSchema).alias("sensorReading"))
```

Comment: If the number of kinds for sensor types is small, you can try "CASE WHEN" and put different approach on reading "Parameter" per the value of "Sensor_Type". I guess the type of output of "Parameter" should be all same and deterministic, as it doesn't make sense for query to support different schema per row.
If the number of kinds for sensor types is huge, you can try wrapping the code to read "Parameter" as UDF and pass the values of twos ("Sensor_Type" and "Parameter") as a parameters of UDF.

Comment: @JungtaekLim , Thanks for your comment, We are planning to have a dynamic nature, such that user could add a new sensor type any time and the spark should be able to process the same. The schema (Parameters) of newly added sensor Types can fetch from DB., That is the reason why I thought of passing sensor_type as a variable for the JDBC query.

I am not sure my approach is correct here, Does spark structured streaming suit for such dynamic use cases?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it only works when schema of sensor types are all same. What you run is a SQL query which each operation has input schema and output schema. If you want to have flexibility with schema you may end up with dealing them as String type and having branches (like CASE WHEN).

Comment: @JungtaekLim Regarding the case when approach, I found a way to get sensor_type's to a list , Now I need to cross check it with the Sensor_Type column in streaming dataframe . How I could perform the same? Could you please guide me?